# IOS side loaded App changing current location

Tags: ios, swift, gps, geolocation

Trying to develop my first application which will just be side loaded to my device. I am unsure if I can even do what I'm looking for; I'm trying to change the current location on my device via my application. I know this is done with the Xcode debugger but can it be done solely on the application with no connection to the computer? Basically I have a few buttons, each one I want to change the location to somewhere different. Do I just code the coordinates to set with the button and thats all? Will this show on my maps application and such? Thanks.

Comment: Stop trying to spoof location, and catch your Pokémon like the rest of us.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Side loaded IOS App that will change GPS location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38350923/side-loaded-ios-app-that-will-change-gps-location)

Answer (score 4):

What you ask is not possible. The GPS hardware is what reports location to the phone. Xcode is able to do this because it is reporting location to the simulator, which has no GPS hardware on its own

Comment: It's worth mentioning that there's good reasons that this isn't possible. First, it's making something that works, stopping working properly. Second, it's outside of the scope of an application; the application should only be able to totally control things inside of it, and not have total control over elements more global to the device. Third, there are many nefarious reasons to want to trick the phone into thinking it's somewhere else.

Comment: You are without question correct. I had chosen to only answer the technical aspect of the question, and not the ethical ones, but nevertheless your points are correct and important